# Stackable PCB Sockets/Headers

Tags: pcb, socket, header

I have two PCBs that I would like to connect/sandwich together via a [**1x5 header**](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Amphenol-FCI/10129378-905004BLF?qs=0lQeLiL1qyav7GYRtFo7TA%3D%3D) on the bottom board and a [**1x5 socket**](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Preci-dip/801-87-005-10-001101?qs=FtMuP6KVi2R108PxLYdAww%3D%3D) on the top board.

The components I have so far seem to work nicely, the only issue is the spacing between the boards. Due to some larger components on the bottom board, I need the spacing of the boards to be greater than 20mm.

I've seen a few board-to-board connectors out there, but they require you to solder both ends to each board, not ideal in my case since the boards need to be removable from one another.

What I need is some sort of "stackable spacer" header/socket combo, something that I can put between the header on the bottom board and socket on the top board.

Does anyone know if there is a product like this? I have thought of just using another socket like the one mounted on the top board, but after referencing the datasheet, the socket pins are too small to fit into the socket receptacles (by 0.1mm!)

Comment: I *think* Samtec makes pin headers to custom lengths. You could also use a very tall pogo pin interposer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some 19mm headers , maybe you can find 25mm ones

Then for structural rigidity put a dummy header on the other side. Maybe you can find a lower profile part.  Make sure you apply polyurethane to the body of the big part to avoid vibration fatigue to the solder joints.

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/527/mtmm_th-1370249.pdf

Comment: Thanks for that datasheet Tony, it was exactly what I needed. Looks like the 19mm dimension is measured from the top of the plastic bit (which itself measures 2.54mm from the bottom). So total height is over 20mm.